# Como setear plantilla del Login que viene por defecto en Django

Tags: django-admin, django-templates

Estuve buscando en las documentaciones sobre como cambiarle la plantilla al login que viene por defecto con django, y sugieren hacer la misma estructura jerarquizara de django donde están las plantillas. En el caso de Django 2.1 que es el que estoy usando viene en alluth/templates/account/login.html, haciendo esto mismo en mi aplicación quedaría de la siguiente manera myapp/templates/allauth/templates/account/login.html. Pero Django sigue usando la que trae por defecto, no coge la plantilla login personalizada que le pongo. Alguien me pudiera ayudar con esto.

Comment: revisa esto creo que es lo que necesitas: http://django-marcador.keimlink.de/es/frontend_login.html

Answer (score 0):

ya resolvi, solo tenia que mover a nivel de las app una carpeta con nombre templates y ahi agregar account/login html, y en el setting subir antes de cargar el modulo auth de django la app mia, con eso Django anula el login que viene por default y muestra el mio, ahora el problema esta en el siguiente, este es el codigo del  login que tengo:

{% load static i18n %}

```
<!-- begin::Head -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page | Login</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Latest updates and statistic charts">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--begin::Web font -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.16/webfont.js"></script>
    <script>
        WebFont.load({
        google: {"families":["Poppins:300,400,500,600,700","Roboto:300,400,500,600,700"]},
        active: function() {
            sessionStorage.fonts = true;
        }
      });
    </script>

    <!--end::Web font -->

    <!--begin::Global Theme Styles -->

    <link href="{% static 'css/base/vendors.bundle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--RTL version:<link href="../../../assets/vendors/base/vendors.bundle.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
    <link href="{% static 'css/base/style.bundle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--RTL version:<link href="../../../assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

    <!--end::Global Theme Styles -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'logos/favicon.ico' %}" />
</head>

<!-- end::Head -->

<!-- begin::Body -->
<body class="m--skin- m-header--fixed m-header--fixed-mobile m-aside-left--enabled m-aside-left--skin-dark m-aside-left--fixed m-aside-left--offcanvas m-footer--push m-aside--offcanvas-default">

    <!-- begin:: Page -->
    <div class="m-grid m-grid--hor m-grid--root m-page">
        <div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-grid m-grid--hor m-login m-login--signin m-login--2 m-login-2--skin-1" id="m_login" style="background-image: url(../../../assets/app/media/img//bg/bg-1.jpg);">
            <div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-login__wrapper">
                <div class="m-login__container">
                    <div class="m-login__logo">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="{% static 'logos/logo-1.png' %}">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="m-login__signin">
                        <div class="m-login__head">
                            <h3 class="m-login__title">Sign In To Admin</h3>
                        </div>
                        <form class="m-login__form m-form login-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login'%}">{% csrf_token%}
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                <input class="form-control m-input m-login__form-input--last" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row m-login__form-sub">
                                <div class="col m--align-left m-login__form-left">
                                    <label class="m-checkbox  m-checkbox--light">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> {% trans 'Remember me' %}
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col m--align-right m-login__form-right">
                                    <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}" id="forget-password" class="forget-password">{% trans 'Forgot Password?' %}</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="m-login__form-action form-actions">
                                <button class="btn btn-focus m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air  m-login__btn m-login__btn--primary" type="submit">{% trans 'Login' %}</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="m-login__signup">
                        <div class="m-login__head">
                            <h3 class="m-login__title">Sign Up</h3>
                            <div class="m-login__desc">Enter your details to create your account:</div>
                        </div>
                        <form class="m-login__form m-form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Fullname" name="fullname">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                <input class="form-control m-input" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                <input class="form-control m-input m-login__form-input--last" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="rpassword">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-group m-form__group m-login__form-sub">
                                <div class="col m--align-left">
                                    <label class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--light">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="agree">I Agree the <a href="#" class="m-link m-link--focus">terms and conditions</a>.
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <span class="m-form__help"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="m-login__form-action">
                                <button id="m_login_signup_submit" class="btn m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air m-login__btn m-login__btn--primary">Sign Up</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <button id="m_login_signup_cancel" class="btn m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air m-login__btn">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="m-login__forget-password">
                        <div class="m-login__head">
                            <h3 class="m-login__title">Forgotten Password ?</h3>
                            <div class="m-login__desc">Enter your email to reset your password:</div>
                        </div>
                        <form class="m-login__form m-form" action="">
                            <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="m_email" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div class="m-login__form-action">
                                <button id="m_login_forget_password_submit" class="btn m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air m-login__btn m-login__btn--primary">Request</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <button id="m_login_forget_password_cancel" class="btn m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air m-login__btn">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="m-login__account">
                        <span class="m-login__account-msg">
                            Don't have an account yet ?
                        </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="javascript:;" id="m_login_signup" class="m-link m-link--light m-login__account-link">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- end:: Page -->

    <!--begin::Global Theme Bundle -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'vendors/base/vendors.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/base/scripts.bundle.js' %}"></script>

    <!--end::Global Theme Bundle -->

    <!--begin::Page Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/login.js' %}"></script>

    <!--end::Page Scripts -->
</body>

<!-- end::Body -->
```

No logro que cuando le doy al boton login me logee, se queda en el mismo login. Alguien puede chekar mi codigo y decirme que me falta?????

---

Ya lo resolví al cambiarle el name de username por login, en la version Django 2.1

Comment: Recuerde **[aceptar su propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**.